# Error IntentService useing gcm

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using this [Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-using-gcm-tutorial/) but after run app crash app and give me this error.

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
Process: package-name, PID: 11869
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/yadbegir.jfa.mansoor.com.yadbegir/files/instant-run/dex/slice-realm-optional-api_82aa9dab5d973e04cc1850ef40d4e3808a75f9c1-classes.dex)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at package-name.service.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:33)
at package-name.service.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:25)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Please Help for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to update [Google Play Services library to version 9.0.2](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2016_-_v92)

The Google Play services version 9.0.1 release is now available. This release fixes the following issues with the version 9.0.0 release:

- Fixes a class change compilation error with [ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)).
- Fixes a [known issue](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#known_issues) with serving Admob ads on devices without the Google Play services APK when your app uses ProGuard post-processing.